# How to save data from Excel to SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I want to create a file in Excel with stored data row by row and then create a command button. Clicking on the button, I would save that data in an appropriate table on SQL server 2008.
Does Excel support this functionality? or Is it possible to do?

Please, somebody, explain me, what do I need to know more about it.

Thanks in Advance.
Bhushan

Comment: What have you tried/where are you getting stuck? [Please see this guide to improve your chances of getting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, you can see: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1540/insert-update-or-delete-data-in-sql-server-from-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible as it can be done using Excel Software Development kit. With in that you can follow the following procedure

1. You can set database credentials in some config file.
2. First row should be name of each column.
3. Second row should be a drop down containing type of data of column.
4. After that you can proceed with data.

This is just to provide you general idea.

Answer (score 0):

From Excel to SQL Server...please see the following URL...

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Excel%20Data%20Export%20to%20SQL%20Server%20Test%20Code

Think of this script as well . . .

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
'TRUSTED CONNECTION
    On Error GoTo errH

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intImportRow As Integer
    Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String

    Dim server, username, password, table, database As String


    With Sheets("Sheet1")

            server = .TextBox1.Text
            table = .TextBox4.Text
            database = .TextBox5.Text


            If con.State <> 1 Then

                con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                'con.Open

            End If
            'this is the TRUSTED connection string

            Set rs.ActiveConnection = con

            'delete all records first if checkbox checked
            If .CheckBox1 Then
                con.Execute "delete from tbl_demo"
            End If

            'set first row with records to import
            'you could also just loop thru a range if you want.
            intImportRow = 10

            Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
                strFirstName = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
                strLastName = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)

                'insert row into database
                con.Execute "insert into tbl_demo (firstname, lastname) values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & "')"

                intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
            Loop

            MsgBox "Done importing", vbInformation

            con.Close
            Set con = Nothing

    End With

Exit Sub

errH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Also, please see the following VBA scripts...

```
Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS"
'cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=Yes"


'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = '2013-01-22' WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL


'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```